# The OutputStream of an SSLSocket is "blocking"

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, blocking, outputstream

The problem: Sometimes when the client disconnects from my program / server while data is being sent, the write method of my program blocks.

This is the loop my write method is in:

```
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

        
        /* I have left out the code that generates the data to be sent for a better overview */

        try {
            // Up to this point the code will run normally
            out.write(data.bytes, 0, data.num);
            /* Sometimes the code after the write method does not run.
               It is like the write method blocks permanently. */
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }

    }
```

I tried to break the blockage by ...
closing the SSLSocket,
closing the Input and output stream,
using the flush method,
using interrupt and join method on the thread,
and by reading and writing with the input and output streams.
None of this works.

I noticed that when I create the OutputStream like this
`out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());`
the "blocking" behavior occurs much less often than if I create the OutputStream like this.
`out = socket.getOutputStream();`
I don't know why but there is a clear difference.

Is there a way to prevent the "blocking" entirely or is there a way to free a "blocked" process?

Comment: What Java version do you use? I am not sure if it makes a difference but I would add something like `socket.isClosed()` to the while break condition (writing to a closed socket should trigger an IOException but just to make sure)...

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your comment!

Java version:
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)

I tried `! Socket.isClosed ()` and other conditions for the while loop. Unfortunately it makes no difference.

If I try to close the socket with another thread or to write to the output stream, these methods also "block".

Unfortunately, an exception is not triggered. Do you happen to have an idea how I could trigger any exception?

Comment: Even without Exception you can get the stack trace and check where it blocks. Development IDS support this when run the app in debug mode, alternatively you can connect to the JVM and check the threads via "Java Mission Control" or "Visual VM". As we are talking about network traffic I would recommend to also check the actual network traffic via Wireshark. I already had the case where a switch just "forgot" the connection and thus the TCP RST packets were never received by the server.

Comment: @Robert Oh I didn't know I could get the stack trace without an exeption! Thank you very much for the help! I will of course write an answer when I find a solution to my problem.

Comment: SSL writes are a little different than plain socket writes because an SSL write can trigger a (blocking) read due the way the SSL/TLS protocol works. I have no idea if that's what is happening here.